# Sending POST request using PHP

Tags: php, http, post, http-post

I'm trying to send about 5000 HTTP POST request using PHP in an hour and get a JSON data as response for each one. Already I know these following four ways:

1. POSTing from PHP Curl
2. POSTing from Pecl_Http
3. POSTing from Pecl_Http: the OO interface
4. POSTing from file_get_contents

My problem is I don't know which one should I use in case of best performance.

- Would you please explain pros and cons of each way?
- Are there any other ways?
- How can I POST in parallel? Of course I need each response.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference between these. A POST is a POST, no matter how you do it, 99% of the time is going to be spent over the wire.

If you need to make that many requests, consider running your script from the command line. Then you can launch the same command line several time at the same time.

Comment: Yeah I have CRON job for running the script.

Comment: @Tooraj, yes that's the way to go.

Comment: Unless you've got a flakey/slow network connection, and/or are posting large amounts of data, the TCP connection overhead and waiting for the remote server to respond are going to be the biggest time consumers, and the ones you have the least control over.